# What is nvme0n2 on MacBookPro13,1?

Tags: hard-drive, dual-boot

While trying to install (dual-boot) Pop!_OS 20.10 I found /dev/nvme0n2 of size 8KiB on my MacBookPro13,1 which made the live-installer of PopOS crash just before loading the partitioning page and the installer.log say

```
[INFO distinst:crates/disk-ops/src/parted.rs:31] opening disk at /dev/nvme0n2
[INFO distinst:crates/disk-ops/src/parted.rs:37] unable to open disk; creating new table on it
[INFO distinst:ffi/src/disk.rs:452] unable to probe devices: failed to create new partition table on "/dev/nvme0n2": Invalid argument (os error 22)
[ERROR distinst:ffi/src/lib.rs:48] libdistinst: pointer in FFI is null
```

Gparted fails to read nvme0n2 with `Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/nvme0n2`.

/dev/nvme0n1, which is my nvme-drive works just fine. So, what is nvme0n2? It does not show up on macOS and Google does not give many results either.

Answer (score 0):

I think that /dev/nvme0 is the controller, and /dev/nvme0n1 and /dev/nvme0n2 are the first and second disks found on that controller, even if it's not usable.